# I want to exclude some files from my rsync jenkins job after the webhook triggers

Tags: git, jenkins

I am currently having the setup where check-ins from git using webhook trigger Jenkins. I want to exclude some of the files with some pattern(*.txt) to remove from the rsync up job that gets pushed to the servers.

I tried installing conditional build plugin and tried to give the option not to run if the *.txt file exists in the build but no luck. I am new to Jenkins and so not sure what steps I am missing here. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not solve this with Jenkins, but rather with `rsync`. There is a parameter `--exclude` which takes a file pattern like `*.txt`. Check [this article](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders/) and `man rsync` for more information.